# Is there an ARM Neon Gather Instruction?

Tags: c++, arm, simd, avx, neon

Is there an ARM Neon SIMD Gather instruction?

I am looking for an equivalent to the following Intel Intrinsic instruction:

```
 _mm_i32gather_ps(blob, index, 4);
```

I can find related instructions such as:

- [`svld1_gather`](https://developer.arm.com/architectures/instruction-sets/intrinsics/#q=vld1_gather) in the arm developer manual
- Google Highway also has a [`GatherIndex`](https://github.com/google/highway/blob/6d85fbd87194ccce127e70aa395e57be1a7da2a8/g3doc/quick_reference.md) function

Although these functions are related, I do not see an equivalent and am asking myself whether such loads are supported on Arm Neon.

Comment: NEON no, I don't think so.  Only SVE.  It requires somewhat specialized hardware to implement efficiently, like on x86 the initial implementation in Haswell (AVX2) was not very fast, but got better in Broadwell and again in Skylake, and has continued to improve.  With ARM NEON historically targeting lower-end CPUs than Intel big-cores, it makes some sense they wouldn't have added it until SVE.  Especially if there haven't been continual new additions of new NEON instructions.

Comment: There have been some instruction groups added to NEON (crc, crypto, float16, complex arithmetic, dot product, etc) but they're all just fancy kinds of arithmetic.  Indeed, nothing relevant to memory access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no gather in Neon. Scatter/gather instructions are explicitly one of the improvements of SVE/SVE2 over Neon (and thus reasons to move to SVE/SVE2, along with scalable vectors for different targets etc)
See [SVE documentation](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/102476/0100/Introducing-SVE) for more.

Answer (score 2):

For gathers from small tables NEON has the `vtbl` and `vtbx` instructions which let you create a value from a table lookup, where the table is held in 1/2/4 registers.